# Pervasive SQL subquery with variable

Tags: sql, variables, subquery, pervasive

To get the data I need in less than several minutes of execution, I have 2 separate queries:

```
select
    ' ' as POHI_ACD,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(OePo_Header.PO_ID)) as POHI_PONUM,
    ' ' as POHI_POTYP,
    ' ' as POHI_VND,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(OePo_Header.CLIENT_ID)) as POHI_CO,
    'B1' as POHI_WA,
    'n/a' as PODI_COMMNT, -- Comment filled in separate query
    ' ' as POHI_CUSER,
    ' ' as POHI_TSCRT,
    ' ' as POHI_PGMUP,
    ' ' as POHI_USRUP,
    '01/01/0001 00:00:00' as POHI_TSLUP,
    ' ' as POHI_FILEPATH
from (
        OePo_Header
        inner join OePo_Item 
        on OePo_Header.PO_ID = OePo_Item.PO_ID
    )
    left join OePo_Remarks
    on OePo_Header.WHSE_INST_ID = OePo_Remarks.AUTOKEY
    and OePo_Header.PO_ID = OePo_Remarks.PO_ID
where (
        (OePo_Item.UNITQTY_ORDER = 1)
        and (OePo_Header.SHIPTO_ID like '%*B1')
        and(OePo_Item.CLOSED_FLG = 'N')
        and(OePo_Item.INVOICED_COUNT = 0)
        and(OePo_Item.ITEM_TYPE = '2')
        and(OePo_Item.VENDOR_ID <> 'WHSE')
    )
group by
    LTRIM(RTRIM(OePo_Header.PO_ID)),
    LTRIM(RTRIM(OePo_Header.CLIENT_ID)),
    'B1',
    if(TEXT = Null, '', TEXT),
    '',
    '',
    OEPO_HEADER.PO_ID
order by
    OEPO_HEADER.PO_ID;
```

and

```
select
    OePo_Remarks.TEXT as POHI_COMMNT
from (
    OePo_Remarks
    inner join OePo_Header
    on OePo_Remarks.AUTOKEY = OePo_Header.WHSE_INST_ID
    and OePo_Remarks.PO_ID = OePo_Header.PO_ID
    )
where
    OePo_Remarks.PO_ID like '%208672%' -- fill in with appropriate PO num from outer code, 208672 is just an example. (PO_IDs can be padded, hence the %s)
    OePo_Remarks.zflags like '%w%'
```

Instead of combining the data in the code which calls both queries, how would I set up a subquery which uses data from the outer query to get what I'm looking for? Something like:

```
select
    ' ' as POHI_ACD,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(OePo_Header.PO_ID)) as POHI_PONUM,
    ' ' as POHI_POTYP,
    ' ' as POHI_VND,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(OePo_Header.CLIENT_ID)) as POHI_CO,
    'B1' as POHI_WA,
    -- subquery start
    ( select
        OePo_Remarks.TEXT
    from (
        OePo_Remarks
        inner join OePo_Header
        on OePo_Remarks.AUTOKEY = OePo_Header.WHSE_INST_ID
        and OePo_Remarks.PO_ID = OePo_Header.PO_ID
        )
    where (
        OePo_Remarks.PO_ID like CONCAT('%', POHI_PONUM, '%') -- Here is where I need the correct PONUM from the outer query.
        and OePo_Remarks.zflags like '%w%'
        )
    ) as POHI_COMMNT, --subquery end
    ' ' as POHI_CUSER,
    ' ' as POHI_TSCRT,
    ' ' as POHI_PGMUP,
    ' ' as POHI_USRUP,
    '01/01/0001 00:00:00' as POHI_TSLUP,
    ' ' as POHI_FILEPATH
from (
        OePo_Header
        inner join OePo_Item 
        on OePo_Header.PO_ID = OePo_Item.PO_ID
    )
    left join OePo_Remarks
    on OePo_Header.WHSE_INST_ID = OePo_Remarks.AUTOKEY
    and OePo_Header.PO_ID = OePo_Remarks.PO_ID
where (
        (OePo_Item.UNITQTY_ORDER = 1)
        and (OePo_Header.SHIPTO_ID like '%*B1')
        and(OePo_Item.CLOSED_FLG = 'N')
        and(OePo_Item.INVOICED_COUNT = 0)
        and(OePo_Item.ITEM_TYPE = '2')
        and(OePo_Item.VENDOR_ID <> 'WHSE')
    )
group by
    LTRIM(RTRIM(OePo_Header.PO_ID)),
    LTRIM(RTRIM(OePo_Header.CLIENT_ID)),
    'B1',
    if(OePo_Remarks.TEXT = Null, '', OePo_Remarks.TEXT),
    '',
    '',
    OePo_Header.PO_ID
order by
    OePo_Header.PO_ID;
```

Using a single much less efficient query, I can get the data I need in a single query, but it takes several minutes to execute in this query, and could take orders of magnitude longer in a separate query which looks for similar (but not same) data. Is there a way to have this work with variables? (Unless there is a `join` combination which will allow me to collect the right data in less than several minutes?)

Comment: Why do you need to trim your id values?

Comment: Old habit in my company due to various padding being added to things in that particular database, so I am told. (Still relatively new here). Also these queries originally were translated from Access queries, which had trims all over the place.

Comment: Well I'd say that's gotta be a major contributor to your issues. Try testing the speed without all the trimming and wildcard matching on ID values.

Comment: Have you used the Query Plan and Query Plan Viewer?  That might show some reason for the performance. How many records does the sub query return?  How many does the main query return?  Those LIKE statements are going to impact performance.

Comment: I'll take a look at Query Plan/Viewer, and in the subquery above, only 1 record should be returned, but on the related query which is not actually on this page, more than 1 may be returned. I'll see if I can tune the original query to avoid the subquery mess.

Comment: Turns out that a clarification of what tables refer to what exactly cleared the problem up into a single optimized query - problem was on the programmer end, not the program end! That being said, the original question stands for future reference: Are subqueries with variables in Pervasive SQL possible?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to default a load of column values in to make them match but I would try using a union to make your two selects come out as a single result set. Its not uncommon to find two simpler queries combined in a union more quicker than one complicated query in my experience.

Comment: I found a workaround, but to the title question and so I can accept an actual answer, does this mean that a subquery with a variable dependent on the outer query is not possible?